# How can I modify my code to use SciKit Learn KMeans for a mutli-feature data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I currently have the below which is a single feature, I'm looking to utilize up to 500 dimensions of data. I'm not sure how I can manipulate x and y, or introduce new arrays, to allow for more features.

What I really would like to do is have one main ID, or row, and say what is the most similar row to this row, which has greater than 500 columns or features. Can I manipulate the arrays to do this, or is there a better way to consider this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

x = [1,5,1.5,8,1,9]
y = [2,8,1.8,8,0.6,11]

# plt.scatter(x,y)
# plt.show()

X = np.array( list(zip(x,y)) )
print(X)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers
labels = kmeans.labels

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["g.","r."]

for i in range(len(X)):
print("coordinate: ",X[i],"label: ",labels[i])
plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize=10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],marker ="x",s=150,linewidths=5,zorder=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. As far as I can tell, your current code clusters `6 samples` with `2 features (x,y)` into `2 clusters`. How this relates to the things you state in the text is unclear. What is the "single feature"? What would the "500 dimensions" look like? Also, if your goal is to find the most similar row in a data set to some 'target row', you're not looking to do clustering, you're looking to find a nearest neighbor, for which you could e.g. use `scipy.spatial.KDTree`.

Comment: Hi WhoisJack - I believe i'm under the impression that the 2 features can't be made into 3 very easily, or 500, etc.

Comment: Methods such as `kmeans` and `KDTree` are absolutely able to handle high-dimensional feature spaces. Your example array `X` of shape `(6,2)` represents `6 samples` with `2 features`. If you get your actual data into an array of shape `(N,500)`, it should work just fine.